# Accessing tips for a venue using the FourSquare API with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foursquare

I'm trying to get a list of tips for each venue when performing a search using the explore endpoint of the `FourSquare` API to see popular venues nearby.

I'm getting a JSON response with venues in it and can access most of its properties. However, I don't know how to access the tips object that is returned and is part of the venue object. 
This is the page on `FourSquare` describing the response:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue

This is what I'm using to access the venue object:

```
var venues = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];
```

How do I access the tips object that is inside this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
var items = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];

var itemVenue = {}; /* It is an object item venue */
var itemTips = []; /* It is an array of item tips */

for(var item in items){
    itemVenue = items[item]['venue'];
    itemTips = items[item]['tips'];

    console.log('Venue Name: ', itemVenue.name);
    console.log('Item tips count: ', itemTips.length);        

    /* Here we can loop all tips of  this item */
    var itemTip = {}; /* tip is an object */
    for(var tip in itemTips){
        itemTip = itemTips[tip];
        console.log('Tip text: ', itemTip.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change the word as to in in the for loops so for (item in items) but apart from that it works great!